# Linux distribution for USB that works on 32/64 and on Mac

Tags: boot, uefi, macintosh, distribution-choice, 32bit

I'm looking for a Linux distribution that I can run from USB that works on almost every computer that I will encounter. I need this because I repair computers and want to run all kinds of tools. I want it to run on:

- IA-32 (32 bit) and x86-64 (64 bit) processors
- BIOS and UEFI computers
- PC and Mac (after they switched to Intel)

UEFI computers normally have a BIOS compatibility mode, but, if I understood it correctly, Mac computers don't have this. I have here temporarily an iMac from Mid 2010 on which I have tested. The boot option `nomodeset` seems to be required to prevent a black screen when running Linux on this Mac.

I've looked at:

- Slax - works nice, but no UEFI support
- Lubuntu - works, but no UEFI on 32 bit version, so I would need two USB flash drives to cover all requirements, which is not ideal. Also not really made for running from USB (persistence options).
- Knoppix - When running on a Mac, it makes the startup sound, but the screen goes to black before I can enter boot options.
- antiX - Update: seems to work, check my own answer

Is there any distro that satisfies all requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [GRML](http://grml.org/) and [ALT Rescue](http://en.altlinux.org/rescue), maybe.

The former is a very decent specialized recovery/rescue distribution; the latter might be somewhat easier to reach regarding special needs (I maintained it for [many years](http://nightly.altlinux.org/sisyphus/ChangeLog) but am now passing the project to my younger colleague, so not as shameless plug as it used to be; any of the [Regular builds](http://en.altlinux.org/regular)' LiveCDs has gparted and a basic set of rescue tools, Rescue is text-only on intent but has considerably more of those).

GRML has "96-bit" ISO that will get you rolling on both 32- and 64-bit computers; ALT has UEFI shim that should work on 64-bit [RestrictedBoot](http://en.altlinux.org/UEFI_SecureBoot_mini-HOWTO) UEFI (and recently on 32-bit too if the guys didn't break it when updating).

Not sure of Intel Macs though, I have none handy for testing.

PS: you might also find [this](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) immensely useful, and [this](http://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/4957.html) no less entertaining.

Comment: Thanks! At the moment I have antiX running and no time to look at alternatives. But I might take a look at it later.

Comment: The golden rule is "if it works, don't break it" :-)  Glad for you!

Answer (score 2):

How about one USB flash drive with multiple LiveOS on it?

You can put a 32 bit distro and multiple 64 bit distros on one USB key with [Multiboot](http://multibootusb.org/), [Multisystem](http://liveusb.info/) ([English web review](https://www.lifewire.com/create-multiboot-linux-usb-drive-4135593) and [another English review](https://www.unixmen.com/create-multiboot-usb-ubuntu-using-multisystem/)), and [XBOOT](https://sites.google.com/site/shamurxboot/).

Although not exactly what you asked for, it does give you everything on one flash drive.

Answer (score 1):

I got something that seems to work:

Use 32 bit (386) [antiX Linux](https://antixlinux.com/).

I first used [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) on Windows to write it to a USB drive, with MBR as partition scheme. But I had some problems with persistency. Then I used the `live-usb-maker` tool from within antiX to write antiX to an other USB drive. Now it works just fine.

I tested it on my 64 bit PC, a 64 bit Mac (requires `nomodeset` in the boot options) and also on a 32 bit BIOS PC.

Answer (score -2):

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-lightweight-Linux-distro-with-UEFI-support
It say that you can just install a uefi grub on USB and it should be bootable.

Comment: I'll take a look at it if there are no other options. But I'm looking for a distribution that is easy to install, so just downloading an iso and a tool to write that iso to USB. Not manually installing a bootloader.

Comment: Does not answer original question, specifically regarding the 32-bit and 64-bit points.

Comment: @0xSheepdog True, but x86-64 is backwards compatible with IA-32 so this isn't really a problem.

Comment: This *is* a problem when you need to chroot, for the starters...